# submit button not working codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

All i want is echoing 'a' when i click my button.

I have the following code in my `view` :

```
<?php echo form_submit('btnSearch', 'Search');?>
```

And this code in my controller :

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSearch'])) 
{
    echo 'a';
}
```

This is my full code in the controller :

```
public function index() {
    //table     
    $data_umat = $this->backend_m->get_umat()->result();

    $this->table->set_heading(
        'No',
        'Nama',
        'Kelas',
        'Alamat',
        'Sekolah',
        'Nomor Telepon',
        'Keterangan'        
    );

    $table_template = array('table_open' => '<table border="1" id="custom_table">');
    $this->table->set_template($table_template);

    $no = 1;
    foreach($data_umat as $list_temp) 
    {
        $this->table->add_row(
            $no++,
            $list_temp->nama,
            $list_temp->kelas,
            $list_temp->alamat,
            $list_temp->sekolah,
            $list_temp->no_tlpn,
            $list_temp->keterangan
        );
    }

    $data = $this->backend_m->get_kelas()->result();

    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $data['list_kelas'][$row->kelas_id] = $row->kelas;
    }

    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();

    $this->load->view('backend/home_v', $data);

    if(isset($_POST['btnSearch'])) 
    {
        echo 'a';
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
And this is my `view` full code :

```
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>
<div id="side_menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Daftar Umat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Daftar Pengurus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Absensi</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
<form>
<p>Search by Kelas :
<?php echo form_dropdown('kelas_id', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas1"');?> -
<?php echo form_dropdown('kelas_id', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas2"');?>
</p>
<?php echo form_submit('btnSearch', 'Search');?>
<?php echo $table?>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

But the 'a' is not showing when i click the button. Where is my mistake? Thanks :D

Comment: show your view code also

Comment: @EdwinAlex Roger that Sir :D

Comment: Looking at view, you do not have a form to start with.

Comment: you do not have form_open and form_close. So it will not post to controller

Comment: Sorry all, the <form></form> tag is there earlier, but its not working.
@EdwinAlex but when i tried yo use form_open(), its working (i dont know why,i think its same with <form>). Please answer so i can accept it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `form` tag. Please include that.

```
    echo form_open('your_controller_name/index');
    echo form_dropdown('kelas_id', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas1"');
    echo form_dropdown('kelas_id', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas2"');
    echo form_submit('btnSearch', 'Search');
    echo form_close();
```

Now it will post to the controller function `index()`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but why the normal tag <form> is not working? :D

Answer (score 4):

You have not opened the form tag in HTML which you can see as bellow

```
<?php
    echo form_open('Controller/Controller_Function');
    echo form_dropdown('kelas_id', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas1"');
    echo form_dropdown('kelas_id', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas2"');
    echo form_submit('btnSearch', 'Search');
    echo form_close();
?>
```

Now It should work. The first line is similar to

```
<form method="POST" action="Controller/Controller_Function">
```

Now It should be working.

Comment: Sorry i can only accept 1 answer, and he answer first in the comment. Thanks for your help :D